# ActionScript 3.0 : Display images at every 10 seconds while music is playing

Tags: actionscript-3, image, audio

I want to Display images at every 10 seconds while music is playing in Action Script 3.0.
I am very new to As3 . I have started to learn As3.But I need to do this in very quick time.I dont know what is the starting point for acheiving this.please give me some suggestions to do this.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Where do you want to display pictures, what kind of pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerAction);
timer.start();

function  timerAction(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // do your actions here
}
```

and refer the link for help.
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3slideshow/4.php

Comment: Thanks Benny Geo, this is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, [that](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html)'s what you need.
Also, for loading bitmaps, take a look at Loader class. That's how it works:

```
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(/*Here goes path, including extension, for example */"image.gif"));
addChild(loader); // After that you can treat `loader` just like any visible object
```